# Login automatically after PC goes to sleep

Tags: 14.04, password, suspend, users, accounts

My user account's state is this:
[image]

However, when my laptop falls asleep, it prompts me for a password when I awaken it up (by moving the mouse for example). How to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure the Lock Screen option is deselected on your Power Manager, Session and Startup Advanced tab, and on the Screen Saver.
2. Go to Startup Applications and deselect the item titled Screen Locker.

Comment: I had this same issue on Xubuntu 14.04. I'd give more specifics, but I'm on my phone.

Comment: I have tried only setting Automatic login to On, as one can see in my question. I can wait until you log in from a computer, so that can give detailed instructions. Thanks.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/544818/how-do-i-disable-automatic-screen-locking-in-xubuntu

Comment: This will make my PC never fall asleep, or I am wrong?

Comment: Also here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/259190/xubuntu-no-password-request-after-suspension

Comment: @gsamaras It won't.